# How to access variables from a drools rule file in java without declaring them as global?

Tags: java, drools

I am developing an application which uses the following rules file. Is there a way by which i can get the values of the boolean variables `b1`, `b2` and `b3` without declaring them as global?

**Drools file**

```
rule ruleone

when
$fact : AppFact( name == "abcd")

then
boolean b1= $fact.id[422] && $fact.id[423]  &&  $fact.id[372]  &&  $fact.ruleId[373];
boolean b2= b1 && $fact.id[272];
boolean b3= b1 && $fact.id[273];


end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the top of my head, I can think about 2 easy solutions:

### Using a single global service

Declare a single global service that you can use to notify these boolean values. This is convenient if your concern is having a lot of globals in your DRLs.

```
global MyService service;

rule ruleone
when
    $fact : AppFact( name == "abcd")
then
    boolean b1= $fact.id[422] && $fact.id[423]  &&  $fact.id[372]  && $fact.ruleId[373];
    boolean b2= b1 && $fact.id[272];
    boolean b3= b1 && $fact.id[273];

    service.notifyValues(b1, b2, b3);
end
```

This will make the boolean values available to whatever object you configure as `service`.

### Using facts and queries

The idea of this approach is to insert your booleans as facts (wrapped in an object) and then use queries to extrac them from the session.

```
rule ruleone
when
    $fact : AppFact( name == "abcd")
then
    boolean b1= $fact.id[422] && $fact.id[423]  &&  $fact.id[372]  && $fact.ruleId[373];
    boolean b2= b1 && $fact.id[272];
    boolean b3= b1 && $fact.id[273];

    insert(new Result(b1, b2, b3));
end

query getResults()
    $r: Result()
end
```

For a better understanding about queries, please refer to [Drools' documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/drools/release/6.4.0.Final/drools-docs/html_single/#QuerySection).

Hope it helps,